# RealmList sort async?

Tags: java, android, realm

I just wondered if there is a way to sort a `RealmList` asynchronously on Android.

Say I have a realm object called `diaryEntry` which contains a `RealmList` of `Entry` objects:

```
RealmList<Entry> entries;
public RealmList<Entry> getEntries() { return entries; }
```

If i want to sort the RealmList I simply call sort and thats it, it works fine.

```
RealmResults<Entry> sortedEntries = diaryEntry.getEntries().sort("time");
mvpView.bindAndShowEntryList(sortedEntries);
```

The above code however is executed in a Fragment´s `onResumeFragment()` method which gets called when the **Fragment** becomes visible (it´s a custom lifecycle method I introduced) in a **ViewPager**. So obviously it would be nice if I could sort the data in the background and when the fragment becomes visible simply bind the results to the view.

So I came up with a second solution below:

```
entries = realm.where(Entry.class)
                .equalTo("dateId", dateId)
                .findAllSortedAsync("time");
```

Note: `dateId` is an integer and is a **unique ID** for every `Fragment` in the `ViewPager`.
This way I had to add a new indexed integer field dateId to the Entry.class.

```
public class Entry extends RealmObject {
    // Other fields ...
    @Index
    private int dateId;
```

**My question:** Is there a way to sort a `RealmList` asynchronously?
If not, which approach may be better? The first one which ***sorts*** the entries on the **UI thread** but has instant access to a `RealmList` containing all the corresponding `Entry` objects (in average 10-15 Entry objects). 
Or the second approach, which has to find all corresponding `Entry` objects first by their `dateId`, but does all of that **async** without blocking the UI thread?

**Note:** In average there are about 10-15 `Entry` objects for every unique `dateId`, so if a normal user is using my app for 2 years and adds about 15 entries every day there will be about 11000 `Entry` objects in the database. This is obviously a pretty high assumption as no user will add entries every day and not even that much.

Comment: `.findAllSortedAsync("time");` this sorts asynchronously. The `RealmChangeListener` you add to it is called when the initial async evaluation is complete (and on any future change).

Comment: So the second approach would be better, even though the database needs to be queried for the Entry objects first? But I guess the search speed is pretty fast and it is async (that minimal amount of search time doesn´t really matter?) so it´s the better approach, did I understand that right?

Comment: I know it´s off-topic, but is there a way to animate the RecyclerView items using a RealmRecyclerViewAdapter?

Comment: If you use `realm-android-adapters:2.1.0` and `Realm-Java 3.1.4` then it should be animated automatically -- I think second approach is more stable, I guess. Another option would be `diaryEntry.getEntries().where().findAllSortedAsync("time")` although I haven't actually tried that one. Generally if I had to solve this problem, I would go with the 2nd option, so kudos - you seem to have grasped how Realm schema design works :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I´ve testet the above approach and it works fine too. Now I just need to decide which approach is cleaner data model wise. Storing a _RealmList_ of entries or storing an integer ID to find the entries that belong together by a query later on. The animations however, still don´t work although I am using the above libraries. Maybe I´ll start a new question for that. So far thanks for the nice support - Realm <3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
RealmResults<Entry> sortedEntries = diaryEntry.getEntries()
            .where()
            .findAllSortedAsync("time");
```

This will create a query based on your entries list and the query will be executed in the background thread.

Comment: Thanks, I´ve testet it and it works fine too. Now I need to decide which approach is cleaner data model wise. Storing a ´RealmList´ of entries or simple an integer ID to find the entries that belong together by a query later on. Thanks a lot anyway, really nice support - Realm <3